# Trying to recreate Skype conversation panel with Swing

Tags: java, swing, skype

I am trying to recreate the Skype handles instant messaging using Swing components. I am using JList with a custom ListCellRenderer to render each cell in the list. The ListCellRenderer extends a JPanel, the JPanel simply contains a label (where I will put the username) and a JTextArea which is where the users' messages will go. The JTextArea is what Im having problems with.

Here's an image of what I have a the moment -

- Ive removed the scrollpane that automatically comes with the textarea in netbeans.
- I am showing the Navigator, the Design view and the actual program (the list has two elements) in this image.

[image]

1. The the text in textarea is actually much longer than in this image but it is not word wrapping. I have set lineWrap and wrapStyleWord to true in the properties box for this textarea but it doesn't seem to take any effect. I then tried to set maximum size using the properties box and that doesn't have any effect either.
2. Is there any way to control the padding/margins around components with netbeans gui designer. The automatic placement it gives me for spacing between components is either several pixels too small or two large. I need exact placement on the list's cell components.

For reference here is how skype's convesation panel looks (ive added in the red "Brian cs"'s as thats how I will be doing it in my program). As you can see the sentences wrap and there is an appropriate amount of space between cells. So anyone know how to achieve this using Swing?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setLineWrap(true); ?

Comment: I'd use a JTable with custom renderer, not a JList.

Comment: I'd also consider using markup. JLabel will accept HTML and force the linewrap. Something like -> setText("<html>" + text + "</html>" It also makes styling it easier (I can't remember if Skype has rich text or not). Also, set your min/max/preferred size on the components. It will help force the layout. A JTable is going to be much easier to work with  if you're up for doing the rendering. On any long conversation you're going to want the optimization it makes in rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The JTextarea is not the problem. The JList sets the heigth for each row. See JList.setFixedCellHeigth or setPrototypeCellValue